# Can't show Item Component

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm working on React project with  Firebase. I have been successfully fetched datas from Firebase but I have failed to show each item...

**HomeContainer.js**

```
class HomeContainer extends Component {
render() {
    const items = this.props.items;
    return (
    <div>
        <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
            <li>
            <span>{item.name}()</span>
            </li>
        ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

**console.log**

```
items []0: name: "item1"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: what is your error ? and what is the current output

Comment: Looks like there is no item.Id property in the console log, perhaps that is causing the error.

Comment: also add an <ul> in ItemList

Comment: Code looks good - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kzlgod.

Comment: Cross check you have exported all the components and imported correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much. But I can't show Item...

Comment: What happens if you do it in one file? What is the output of your console.log?

Comment: I think its better if you can show the resulting DOM or any console errors you have, because the code you have given seems to be fine, so the problem might be coming from somewhere else

Comment: I have updated to make components in one file. But I couldn't show each item...

Comment: Can you please show us the result of  `this.props.items` ?